# How do I block with my weapon if I have a weapon equipped in one hand and a spell in the other?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

If I have just a weapon equipped (1H or 2H) in the right hand, right clicking will perform a block maneuver.

However, I like to have a melee weapon in one hand (usually right hand) and a spell (flame, lightning or heal) in the other. Is it also possible to block with the hand that has a 1H weapon equipped?

Comment: In the settings is no "Block" button or something similar. So i guess you simply cant. (I havent see a NPC/Enemy block while dual wielding.)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you dual wield at all - including using two weapons or weapon/spell - then you lose the ability to block.

To block you'll either need to unload the spell (empty left hand) or swap it for a shield.

Answer (score 4):

You cannot block when dual-wielding, you need to either equip a shield or leave the left hand empty.

You can block with a 1-handed weapon if your left hand is empty, or you can block with a shield in your left hand.